# Problem with using if/then statement: `((: == : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== ")`

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I try to implement positional parameters in bash script and check them, but have some issue in **if/then** switch statement.

Script:

```
#set "default" parameter
query=""                                          

while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
        -q | --query )          shift
                                query=$1
                                ;;
    esac
    shift
done                            

#query cannot be empty
if (($query == ""))                               
then
 echo 'no query'
 exit
fi

echo "query - $query"
```

All works well when I set the correct parameters:

```
$ ./script.sh -q request
query - request
```

`-q` parameter cannot be empty and I need to validate it. So, when the command line looks like:

```
$ ./script.sh -q
```

or

```
$ ./script.sh
```

I get this error:

```
./main.sh: line 13: ((: == : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "== ")
query -
```

How to correctly implement `if` operator in this case?

Comment: This script lacks a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: Who and why lowered my question ??

Comment: @wjandrea, thanks. Comments I did edit. But all this code I need to put, because `if` statement have different error in different parameters in command line (if parameter exist - I did not get an error in `if...` line), so I showed all.

Comment: The edits are a huge improvement, thanks. I've deleted my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(( ... ))` is for arithmetic evaluation.

You should use `[ ... ]` (just like you did in the `while` condition) or bash's extended test syntax `[[ ... ]]` - and remember to quote "$query" and leave whitespace around the `[` and `]` operators:

```
if [ "$query" == "" ]
```

Alternatively, use the `-z` empty string test:

```
if [ -z "$query" ]
```

---

For general help with questions like this, try [www.shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) or install the `shellcheck` package from the `universe` repository.